# How to manipulate a form input use geolocation instead of plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, local-storage

I have a form on my Jquery Mobile page where the user can insert a start-location and a destination.

These values will be saved inside the localstorage. 
Now I'm trying to manipulate the input like this:

when you type (for instance) 'current' in the input-box, the user's location will be placed inside the localstorage-database instead of the word 'current'.

I already made this script to get the user's location:

```
var geocoder;

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 }

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
        //formatted address
        document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
        //find country name
            for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

                //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                //this is the object you are looking for
                city= results[0].address_components[i];
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
);
}
```

The 2 input fields:

```
<label for="start">Startlocation:</label>
<input type="text" name="start" value="" id="start"/>

<label for="destination">Destination:</label>
<input type="text" name="destination" value="" id="destination"/>
```

I'm very new to javascript and jQuery and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. 
I hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: what is the question? what works or doesn't work in your code, and what errors are being thrown?

Comment: I don't know how to manipulate the input from a user (in javascript/jQuery) just before it is added to the local storage.

Comment: What do you mean with manipulate input? Have you tried `$('input').val('foo')` to set value and `$('input').val()` to get value. Also attach some HTML code to your example. The best would definitely be a jsfiddle.

Comment: from a user-experience point of view, you'd probably be better with a nice button labelled something like 'use current location' next to each input.  When the user hits the button, it looks up the current location, and puts it in the input field.  This makes the operation explicit to the user, and simplifies the code for saving the input field (no special cases required)

Comment: That is a very good alternative! Can you tell how I implement such a button, or where I could find an explanation to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;

if (start == 'current') {
    //set lat & long to current
}
else {
    //read lat & long from input fields
}
```

This bit of logic may prove to be what you're after - however I do tend to agree with [logical Chimp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680345/logical-chimp) that UX is very important, and a "use current location" button may prove to be more useful to the user.